# How to use struct functions in a class outside of main?

Tags: c++, struct

I am attempting to use functions that return a pointer, but I am not sure how to declare them.

Here's my function as I have it currently written, item is the name of my struct, queue is the name of my class - if it were to just be written in main it would simply be: item * divide(item *a):

```
item queue:: *divide(item *a)
{
    item *b, *c;
    b = a;
    c=a->next;
    c=c->next;
    while(c != NULL)
    {
         c=c->next;
         b=b->next;
         if (c!=NULL)
             c=c->next;
    }
c=b->next;
b->next = NULL;
return c;
}
```

What would the correct approach be?

Comment: You seem to be attempting to pass and return pointers, not structs. You should clarify this.

Comment: BTW, what is `queue`?

Comment: That is the class, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the function as:

```
item* queue::divide(item *a);
```

Comment: Ahh, it was super simple after all!  Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `queue` is the class you are mentioning in the title of your question?

The `*` is part of the return type of your function, which stands in front of the scope `queue`. So the correct way to define your finction would be

```
item * queue::divide(item *a)
{
    ...
}
```